# Função retorna valor undefined!

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando pegar a dimensão de uma imagem junto com outros parâmentros durante a previa do upload.

```
<script>


        function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object


    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var imagem = new Image();
      var reader = new FileReader();


          // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.


            imagem.src = e.target.result;

          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img id="foto" class="materialboxed responsive-img" width="650" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');

        var output = [];

        output.push('<li><strong>', '</strong> (', theFile.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
            theFile.size, ' bytes -',imagem.onload = function() {

                  var height = this.height,
                   width = this.width;
                   alert(width+'x'+height);
                    return width+'x'+height+'oi';

                   },'</li>');
            document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            document.getElementById('list1').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';

        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }


  }

  document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

    </script>
```

Eu não estou conseguido capturar o valor retornado da função `imagem.onload`, no entanto o valor aparece no `alert` quando clico para fazer a previa da imagem com a dimensão, sendo que o `return`só dar `undefined`. Onde estou errando? Já tentei usar variáveis para tentar pegar o valor, mas não dá, porém o `alert` exibe o valor.

Comment: Como vc está tentando pegar o valor sem ser no alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que a função `onload` é assíncrona e não retorna nada, ou seja, ela só será executada quando a imagem tiver completamente carregada, por isso não é retornado o valor desejado.

Quando trabalhamos com funções assíncronas, devemos trabalhar com dentro dessa função. Ou seja, só devemos capturar o tamanho da imagem dentro dessa função e não retornar o valor dela.

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    let files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var file of files) {

        // Only process image files.
        if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        var imagem = new Image();
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            // Render thumbnail.
            imagem.src = theFile.target.result;

            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = `<img id="foto" class="materialboxed responsive-img" width="650" src="${theFile.target.result}" title="${escape(theFile.name)}"/>`;

            var output = [];

            imagem.onload = function() {

            var height = this.height,
                 width = this.width;

            let result = `<li><b>${file.type || 'n/a'} - ${file.size} bytes - ${width}x${height}</b>`;

            document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            document.getElementById('list1').innerHTML = `<ul>${result}</ul>`;

            }
        });

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" />

<ul id="list"></ul>
<ul id="list1"></ul>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela explicação @Valdeir Psr, exatamente o que estava precisando. Abraços!